# Is the heat (or work) of the system always equal and opposite to that of the surroundings?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, energy, heat

I know energy must always be conserved by the first law of thermodynamics, but is there ever a scenario in which a system say releases some amount of energy as work, and the surroundings gains equal and opposite energy to that as heat (as opposed to work). As in, must heat/work released be absorbed stritcly as heat/work?

Let me know if I'm misinterpretting something or if this question doesn't make sense.

Comment: The heat supplied to the system comes across the boundary with the surroundings, and comes from the surroundings.  The work done by the system on the surroundings is equal and opposite to the work done by the surroundings on the system.

Comment: Other thing is, the system or surrounding can transform the provided work to heat. The opposite is also possible, but with restrictions of the 2nd TD law.